# i need a script that detects all the long or continous key presses on all browsers

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard-events

I have a script that detects long down key press in opera but not in firfox mozilla..Why is that happening??

Iam using this code:-

```
autoComplete.prototype.keyDown=function(oEvent)
 {
    oEvent=window.event || oEvent;
    iKeyCode=oEvent.keyCode;

    switch(iKeyCode)
    {
       case 38: //up arrow
          this.autoComplete.moveUp();
          break;
       case 40: //down arrow
          this.autoComplete.moveDown();
          break;
       case 13: //return key
          window.focus();
          break;
       case 27: //escape key
          this.autoComplete.oDiv.style.display="none";
          break;
    }
 };
```

This detects my long down key press in opera but not in mozilla .Please suggest me a solution so that my long key presses works fine in all browsers.

EDIT: from long key presses i meant continous key press here.like continous down key press.

Comment: How does this detect a 'long key press'?

Comment: if i alert the value it keeps on giving me alert on my continous down key press in opera but just gives 1 time alert in mozilla even if i kept on pressing down key (code 40)

Comment: what is a continuous keydown? do you mean pressing it repeatedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution...
i was using `oText.onkeydown=this.keyDown;`
 where i should have used `oText.onkeypress=this.keyDown;`

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

for cross browsing use keyCode and which

```
var ikeyCode = oEvent.keyCode || oEvent.which ;
```

now you can detect in all browsers

Comment: its still not detecting continuos down key press in mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd try is to watch the keydown keyup events instead of keypress.
When the keydown occurs, write the time to a variable and start a timer with setTimeout. If keyup happens within maybe 0.3 seconds (so compare the stored time with the current time when this event fires) consider it a tap and call whatever function you need to for that and clear setTimeout.
If your timer reaches 3 seconds like in your example before keyup has been fired, then the user held the button down so show an alert.
Hope that makes sense. I haven't tried it but it sounds good in my head. LOL